# Gnome-tweak-tool not working on Ubuntu Gnome Remix 12.10

Tags: themes, gtk, gnome-tweak-tool

I'm experiencing some problems with Ubuntu Gnome Remix 12.10 64 bits.

[image]

My gnome-tweak-tool doesn't apply themes properly. For the GTK themes, I noted that they are not fully applied. For example, I select Elementary's GTK theme and the window's border (metacity?) still with Adwaita. The theme also looks weird, what led me to believe that there was some engine missing, but that wasn't the case.

The problem got bigger after a recent crash on my Gnome-shell, when I had to use the command gnome-shell --replace on Terminal to get my environment back. Now when I open gnome-tweak-tool, it doesn't display the option of changing shell theme (shows that icon as if I was on Unity or other stuff).

I don't know if this is consequence of any recent update, but I'm using Gnome-shell 3.6.1. I also have gnome3-team ppa installed.

I hope you understand my english :(

Comment: Did this issue occur before you added the gnome-3 ppa?  Perhaps this is a PPA issue that could be reported back to the developers.  Anyway - could you add some links to screenshots so that we can see what you are seeing.  Thanks.

Comment: This may show the problem with the elementary theme, but it also happens with others. As you can see, I can not change shell theme anymore too: ![Bug on theming](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/90061528/Bug.png)

Comment: @fossfreedom , answering to your question, I didn't tested it before adding the ppa. Do you think removing it and doing an apt-get upgrade would help? Anyway, Synaptic says the gnome-tweak-tool that I have installed is not from gnome3 ppa, but from quantal/universe.

Comment: I suspect your issues are with the PPA - however, I dont know that a `sudo ppa-purge` of the PPA will revert successfully.  If this is a new install you could try if you are happy to reinstall if things goes badly.  If in doubt backup your installation with clonezilla which will allow you to reinstall.

Comment: Update: the gnome-shell theming problem is solved, it was a really simple situation."gnome-shell --replace" resets GS settings, so the user-theme extension returned disabled. I can now apply GS themes, but the GTK3 remain with the same problem. I'll try the purge idea :P

Comment: Didn't solved :( . Purging the ppa reverts thing that were installed by it (like my nautilus). Anyway, I'm not with time for another reinstall and I'm kinda satisfied with Adwaita for now. If anyone out there find a solution... I'll post any news here too. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried installing the unico engine, elementary gtk requires it. I had a similar problem until it was installed.

Comment: @Purplerob, strangely, I've already installed gtk3-engines-unico, and it still with this weird behavior. :(